# How to stop all processes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I have a job failing because of blocking and what I am thinking to do is stop all the transactions to the database while I am running that job to avoid the blocking. So, can anyone help on how to stop all transactions and then run that job?

Comment: If it is production system then you should resolve root cause.Single mode is not a silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first need to discover the root cause but if it is definitely needed then you may want to do following -

1. Run below code in a cursor-

   ```
    SELECT conn.session_id
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sess
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS conn
    ON sess.session_id = conn.session_id;
   ```
2. In the cursor , take each session id(@sessionId) in a variable and use following -

   ```
   kill @sessionId
   ```

Below is the complete code -

```
    DECLARE @session_id int
    declare Mycursor cursor for 
       SELECT conn.session_id
       FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sess
       JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS conn
       ON sess.session_id = conn.session_id

   OPEN Mycursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM Mycursor INTO @session_id 
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

   BEGIN  
       Exec ('kill ' + @session_id)

    FETCH NEXT FROM Mycursor INTO @session_id  

  END   
 CLOSE Mycursor;  
 DEALLOCATE Mycursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to solve a problem before you have time to look into the root issue. So with that in mind, you could create a scheduled task to just restart SQL Server (https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/11/03/sql-server-powershell-way-of-restarting-sql-server-service/). I don't recommend this as a permanent solution but it can get you by if necessary.

There are various ways your problem might be resolved. With the limited info you've provided, I'll offer a few ideas:

1) Add SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED wherever it's reasonable to do so (both on the job that's failing and on any other SQL in your procs or code). You *don't* want to use this with things that need to be absolutely precise. For example, don't use it with anything involving money. But it's generally very safe to use (Some idealists will argue about this... if you're an idealists then ignore this advice. If you're a pragmatist then this is a must).

Also WITH (NO LOCK) does the same thing but on a table by table basis. I will leave it to you to google these terms and learn more about them.

2) Use the Activity Monitor (should be an icon for it in the toolbar of SQL Server Management Studio) to see what's running while the job executes to learn what the problem might be, and you can also use this to kill processes.

3) Use Sql Server Profiler (under tools menu) to see what queries are being run.

4) Use a query to see what all queries are running: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/